# Drawing in a matplotlib widget in QtDesigner

Tags: python, qt, numpy, matplotlib

I created in QtDesigner this QDialog:

[image]

I would like to know how can I draw something in this Matplotlib widget that I put there. I mean, if I write some code to create a matplotlib figure without Qt Designer, I can write something like:

```
self.figure_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())

self.axes = self.figure_canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)

x = np.arange(0,5,0.5)
y = np.sin(x)
```

and then draw doing:

`ax.plot(x,y)` or `self.axes.plot(x,y)`

How can I access to this widget  to draw something? Hope you can help me.

Comment: You will want to add your `FigureCanvas` to the widget which based on your screenshot should be accessible within your `QMainWindow` class as `self.matplotlibwidget`. Then you can call `self.matplotlibwidget.addWidget(self.figure_canvas)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried doing exactly this before, and I get an error saying `matplotlibwidget object has no attribute addwidget`.

Comment: Oh ok so you've already got the widget. Sorry mis-read that. You should be just able to use the widget to an an axes directly. `self.matplotlibwidget.axes.plot(x,y)`

Comment: Yes, it works!! Thank you so much. Now i understand a bit more about Qt Designer. Thank you again.

Comment: Great. I've added it as a formal solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot that you have provided, it seems that the `MatplotlibWidget` should be accessible as `self.matplotlibwidget` from within your `QMainWindow` class. This is because of the value listed in the "Object" column of the Object Inspector.

You can use this object *directly* to add plots to your GUI.

```
self.matplotlibwidget.axes.plot(x, y)
```