# How do I remove the margins around the mplwidget's canvas?

Tags: qt, matplotlib, pyqt, matplotlib-widget

I am not sure why the canvas inside [mplwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44029435) has some margin on all sides even when the layout margins have been set to 0.

In Qt Designer:

[image]

Runtime:

[image]

The same issue can be seen in this [sample chapter](https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/sample_chapters/7900-matplotlib-for-python-developers-sample-chapter-6-embedding-matplotlib-in-qt-4.pdf) of the Matplotlib for Python Developers ebook (see page 38).

I've been trying out different examples and I noticed that this issue does not exist in simpler layouts:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding `self.vbl.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` inside `MPLWidget` itself?

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.