# Event onclick() Matplotlib to generate data

Tags: python, matplotlib, onclick

We want to save the points that we have clicked on a list with the coordinates or in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib does have buttons, see the example code [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/buttons.html), however you might want to look at using something like PyQT5 to create a UI for this purpose. You can setup a GUI quickly with [QTDesigner](https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download), then use promote a widget to a matplotlib graph (see [this](https://www.learnpyqt.com/tutorials/embed-pyqtgraph-custom-widgets-qt-app/) tutorial) and link [matplotlib's "on click" event handler](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/event_handling.html) to whatever purpose you would like to achieve.

Comment: Let me see if i have understood what you have explain to me. I have to create a GUI with pyqt but i can´t add a graph of the qt designer. Instead of that i have to transform a widget into a matplotlib graph. Then, can i connect some buttons with the matplotlib graph ?

Comment: Thats correct, see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947318/plotting-matplotlib-figure-inside-qwidget-using-qt-designer-form-and-pyqt5 to see how to work with matplotlib graphs with PyQt5. It will take a bit of playing around to understand how PyQt5 works, but have a play around and try and figure it out, its the best way to learn imo.

Comment: Okey ! I will investigate on that and then try to make it possible. Possibly i will post more questions about that because i have never used python before and that is my first time.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible with matplotlib, however without a minimum working example it's difficult to give you a full answer. For this kind of project, I've worked with Jupyter notebooks as they allow you to define pressable buttons through widgets (for example [here](https://medium.com/@jdchipox/how-to-interact-with-jupyter-33a98686f24e)).

I'd start by having a look at [matplotlib event handling](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/event_handling.html), and for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521120/store-mouse-click-event-coordinates-with-matplotlib) for how to record an `onclick` event.

Comment: Wow i didn´t know that. But the problem is that i have to creat the GUI application with pycharm. I saw that qt have a lot of widgets and options to create an interface and that is i choose that package, but now i don´t know what i should do.....