# connecting mouse clicks to pyqt5 GUI label

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have a set of routines that essentially mirror the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947318/plotting-matplotlib-figure-inside-qwidget-using-qt-designer-form-and-pyqt5), except that I have my plot function in its own class that I import. I do this instead of leaving the code as a method within the MyApp class as the solution has in the given link. I make the code to plot the data in its own file because the actual code is very verbose.

My goal: I am trying to make it such that clicking on the graph will change a label in the GUI.

I've tried researching signals/slots and inheritance, but can't grasp how they can connect or apply when a module load is involved. Keep in mind I'm creating the GUI in PyQtDesigner.

Here is my code

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from timeseries import plotData
import design

class MyApp(QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow, plotData):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.x = [1,2,3,4,5]
        self.y = [1,2,3,4,5]
        
         # Button click plots the timeseries in the first timeseries plot widget
        self.pushButton_plotData.clicked.connect(lambda: self.plot())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # Create GUI application
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MyApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

mplwidget.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as Canvas
import matplotlib
# Ensure using PyQt5 backend
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')


# Matplotlib canvas class to create figure
class MplCanvas(Canvas):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = Figure(dpi=100)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        
        Canvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        Canvas.setSizePolicy(self, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
                             QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        Canvas.updateGeometry(self)

        # Call when user clicks in the plot window
        Canvas.mpl_connect(self, s='button_press_event', func=self.get_coord)
        
    def get_coord(self, event):
        if event.button == 1:
        
            # Get the x coordinate of the mouse cursor in data coordinates
            ix = event.xdata
            print(ix)
            
            # GOAL: Want to be able to execute:
            # self.textBrowser_X1.setText(str(ix[0])) 
            # where textBrowser_X1 is the name of a line edit widget
            

# Matplotlib widget
class MplWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)   # Inherit from QWidget
        self.canvas = MplCanvas()                  # Create canvas object
        self.vbl = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()         # Set box for plotting
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(self.vbl)
```

timeseries.py

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class plotData(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        
    def plot(self):
         self.plotWidget.canvas.ax.plot(self.x, self.y)
         self.plotWidget.canvas.draw()
```

design.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1216, 379)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_plotData = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_plotData.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(216, 20, 96, 33))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton_plotData.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_plotData.setObjectName("pushButton_plotData")
        self.plotWidget = MplWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.plotWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 75, 1177, 234))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.plotWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.plotWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.plotWidget.setObjectName("plotWidget")
        self.textBrowser_X1 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_X1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(132, 21, 75, 30))
        self.textBrowser_X1.setObjectName("textBrowser_X1")
        self.label_X1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_X1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 22, 170, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_X1.setFont(font)
        self.label_X1.setObjectName("label_X1")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1216, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_plotData.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Plot Data"))
        self.label_X1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X position 1"))

from mplwidget import MplWidget
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that there are many redundant things. For example because it is necessary that PlotWidget is a QWidget that only has the canvas if the canvas is a QWidget, another example is the class plotData that inherits unnecessarily from FigureCanvas in addition to doing a redundant task.

Considering the above, the solution is:

**mplwidget.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as Canvas
import matplotlib

# Ensure using PyQt5 backend
matplotlib.use("QT5Agg")


class MplWidget(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Canvas.__init__(self, Figure(dpi=100))
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding
        )
        self.updateGeometry()

        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
```

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

import design


class MyApp(QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        self.y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

        self.pushButton_plotData.clicked.connect(self.plot)
        self.plotWidget.mpl_connect(s="button_press_event", func=self.get_coord)

    def plot(self):
        self.plotWidget.ax.plot(self.x, self.y)
        self.plotWidget.draw()

    def get_coord(self, event):
        if event.button == 1:
            ix = event.xdata
            self.textBrowser_X1.setText(str(ix))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Create GUI application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MyApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you. So am I forced to have the plot method under MyApp? Or can I import it as I had done in my post?